# How do I restriction a Google Places Search to a specific country?

Tags: google-places-api

The documentation says how I can limit searches to a country by using componentRestrictions. However, the documentation apparently only relates
to JavaScript.

I'm doing a regular request from a PHP application, and need to limit a place
search to a country. However, I can't see how I can limit search results to a country using a regular GET request.

Comment: what's your get request URL looks like now? Can't you just add `components=country:XX`?

Comment: @Bolu : that works! The docs didn't say anything about this. Post your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just add `components=country:XX` to your request URL :)